# Reset images position with saved coordinates using jQuery Draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

I implemented draggable image using jQuery-ui Draggable and saved coordinates into database.

Now I am getting coordinates and images url in xml format.

I want to reset the image position. where it was saved.

============= Here is source code:=============

```
$.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "devices.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) {
                 $(xml).find('device').each(function(){
                    var idText = $(this).attr('id');
                    var longAddress = $(this).find('longAddress').text();
                    var imgSrc = $(this).find('type').text();
                    var xAxis = $(this).find('x-axis').text();
                    var yAxis = $(this).find('y-axis').text();

                    var oNewImg = document.createElement('img');
                    oNewImg.id = idText;
                    oNewImg.src = imgSrc;                                                         

                    document.body.appendChild(oNewImg);

                    var originalLeft = parseInt($('#'+oNewImg.id).position().left);

                    $('#'+oNewImg.id).css('left', (xAxis) + 'px');
                    $('#'+oNewImg.id).css('top', (yAxis) + 'px');});
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can get an idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound funny, but why don't you do it? Query the database and for each image output:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
      // SQL query
      $buffer = mysql_query($q);
      while($v = mysql_fetch_assoc($buffer)) {
         echo '<img src="'.$v['url'].'" style="top: '.$v['top'].'px; left: '.$v['left'].'px" />'; 
       }
    ?>
</div>
        <style>
            .container {
               width: 100%;
               height: 100%;
               position: relative;
            }
            .container img {
               position: relative;
            }
        </style>
```

If you got the jQuery part, and storing the images locations in the db, I don't see how you could have problems displaying them...

Comment: My page is just html page and i am using jquery.ajax() to retrive the data. so i am creating dynamic image component on page.

Comment: and how do you store the positions in the database then?

Comment: $(function() {

  $(".draggable").draggable(

  {

   drag: function(event, ui) {
    $(".draggable").css("opacity", "0.7"); 
    var originalLeft = parseInt($(this).position().left);
    var originalTop = parseInt($(this).position().top);
    var sLeftRef = (originalLeft - parseInt($("#area_map").position().left));
    var sTopRef = (originalTop - parseInt($("#area_map").position().top));
 // here i send data by appending url to save position
   },
   cursor: "move"

  });
  

 });

Answer (score 0):

This might helps all who are looking for a JqueryUI draggable with reset to original position on a button click either vertical-align or horizontal align. `Fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/JunaidAli/wp1n796q/321